# How to select in join fetch QueryDSL JPAQuery?

Tags: java, join, fetch, querydsl

I have an application with QueryDSL JPAQuery. Here it is:

```
JPAQuery<MyWrapper> searchQuery
        = queryFactory.select(Projections.constructor(MyWrapper.class,
        deviceGroup.id,
        deviceGroup.name,
        deviceGroup.orientation,
        deviceGroup.location,
        deviceGroup.customer,
        workgroup.account,
        Expressions.as(queryFactory.select(device.count())
            .from(device)
            .where(device.group.id.eq(deviceGroup.id)), "displaysQty"),
        Expressions.as(queryFactory.select(device.count())
            .from(device)
            .where(device.group.id.eq(deviceGroup.id),
                device.status.eq(DeviceStatus.HEALTHY)), "healthyQty"),
        Expressions.as(queryFactory.select(device.count())
            .from(device)
            .where(device.group.id.eq(deviceGroup.id),
                device.status.eq(DeviceStatus.NO_SYNC)), "noSyncQty"),
        Expressions.as(queryFactory.select(device.count())
            .from(device)
            .where(device.group.id.eq(deviceGroup.id),
                device.status.eq(DeviceStatus.NEED_SERVICE)), "needServiceQty"),
        Expressions.as(queryFactory.select(device.count())
            .from(device)
            .where(device.group.id.eq(deviceGroup.id),
                device.status.eq(DeviceStatus.OUT_OF_SERVICE)), "outOfServiceQty")))
        .from(deviceGroup)
        .leftJoin(deviceGroup.customer, workgroup).fetchJoin()
        .leftJoin(workgroup.account, account).fetchJoin()
        .where(predicate)
        .orderBy(sortingParams.toArray(new OrderSpecifier[0]));
```

**MyWrapper** looks like:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyWrapper{

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private DsmsOrientationType orientation;
  private String location;
  private WorkgroupEntityJpa customer;
  private AccountEntityJpa account;

  private long displaysQty;
  private long healthyQty;
  private long noSyncQty;
  private long needServiceQty;
  private long outOfServiceQty;
}
```

And I've got the exception **query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list**.

I've already tried **deviceGroup.customer.account** instead of **workgroup.account**, result was the same.

**UPD**
Here is the **JPAQuery.toString():**

```
select deviceGroupEntityJpa.id, 
        deviceGroupEntityJpa.name, 
        deviceGroupEntityJpa.orientation, 
        deviceGroupEntityJpa.location, 
        deviceGroupEntityJpa.customer, 
        workgroupEntityJpa.account, 
        (select count(deviceEntityJpa)
            from DeviceEntityJpa deviceEntityJpa
            where deviceEntityJpa.group.id = deviceGroupEntityJpa.id) as displaysQty, 
        (select count(deviceEntityJpa)
            from DeviceEntityJpa deviceEntityJpa
            where deviceEntityJpa.group.id = deviceGroupEntityJpa.id and deviceEntityJpa.status = ?1) as healthyQty, 
        (select count(deviceEntityJpa)
            from DeviceEntityJpa deviceEntityJpa
            where deviceEntityJpa.group.id = deviceGroupEntityJpa.id and deviceEntityJpa.status = ?2) as noSyncQty, 
        (select count(deviceEntityJpa)
            from DeviceEntityJpa deviceEntityJpa
            where deviceEntityJpa.group.id = deviceGroupEntityJpa.id and deviceEntityJpa.status = ?3) as needServiceQty, 
        (select count(deviceEntityJpa)
            from DeviceEntityJpa deviceEntityJpa
            where deviceEntityJpa.group.id = deviceGroupEntityJpa.id and deviceEntityJpa.status = ?4) as outOfServiceQty
from DeviceGroupEntityJpa deviceGroupEntityJpa
  left join fetch deviceGroupEntityJpa.customer as workgroupEntityJpa
  left join fetch workgroupEntityJpa.account as accountEntityJpa
```

Answer (score 0):

According to error message, join fetch doesn't need here, because this is a performance hint that forces eager loading of collection.

So use regular join instead of join fetch.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I do need to use `fetch join` due to performance issue (N+1).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a DTO projection, the FETCH directive doesn't make sense here.
The fetch directive tells Hibernate to include the association in the SELECT clause, but you don’t want that because of the DTO projection which does not require the FETCH directive.

Something like:

```
SELECT new EmployeeDTO(e.obj1,e.obj2,e.obj3,e.startDate,e.endDate) 
FROM Employee e 
left outer join fetch e.obj1  
left outer join fetch e.obj2 
left outer join fetch e.obj3
```

doesn't work for the reason above.

**Solution**

Just remove the fetch keyword.